# Product name for service that manages connections

Tags: names, business-language, neologisms, products

Looking for a word or catchy phrase that captures the meaning of "connection management". I work for a web-based company that manages APIs (API's are the connective tissue of the Internet of Things). The best we have come up with is "Spider" since a spider constantly monitors and manages its web. Thanks!

Comment: This will probably be close-voted for being off-topic, but I might be able to help you a bit before that happens: it totally doesn't matter. [Mashery](http://mashery.com) sounds similar to what you do, and you'll notice its name/logo don't really explain anything.

Comment: "Spider" already has a cyber-meaning.  The "connective" of "connective tissue" has little metaphorical relevance to the connectivity of the internet which in turn would seem to have little to do with "managing" APIs.  Perhaps a little more description of what your company is doing would help with the figurative language.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that describes the service your company provides, or to describe the piece of software that you use to provide that service?

Comment: It would probably be wise to steer clear of any mangling of the word "connect", as that can be twisted into an obscenity fairly easily.  (My choice, BTW, would be "Ernestine".)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes ".

Comment: I suppose I could have phrased the question differently so that it is more centered on accurately describing 'change management / connection management / channel monitoring'. Is there such a word/phrase that describes the process of handling connections? Thanks everyone for the thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

The word ***[silk](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/silk)*** seems like an appropriate metaphor for connective tissue:

> noun
>
> 1.0 [MASS NOUN] A fine, strong, soft lustrous fibre produced by
> silkworms in making cocoons and collected to make thread and fabric.
>
> 1.1 Thread or fabric made from the fibre produced by the silkworm:
> [AS MODIFIER]: a silk shirt
> <sub>*ODO*</sub>

*Silk* is used to describe the *strong* and *flexible* fiber extruded by the spinnerets of a [spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider) to *build* its web, and when used to describe manmade products, it has the connotation of *[smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silk#Physical_properties)* as well as *[resilient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silk#Chemical_properties)*.

*Silk* effectively combines the:

1. concept of *strong flexible connection management*, which is ubiquitous in the world-wide web
2. notion of *smooth resilient operation*, which is the goal of a prrogrammer
3. definition *programming building block*, which is the essence of an [*API*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)

> a set of routines, protocols, and tools for building software
> applications. An API expresses a software component in terms of its
> operations, inputs, outputs, and underlying types. An API defines
> functionalities that are independent of their respective
> implementations, which allows definitions and implementations to vary
> without compromising the interface. A good API makes it easier to
> develop a program by ***providing all the building blocks***. A programmer
> then puts the blocks together.
> <sub>*wikipedia.org **emphasis** added*</sub>

*Silk* has the added connotation of *distinguished elegance*.

Answer (score 0):

> Callmanager
>  Communications Manager
>  Gatekeeper
>  Controller

Comment: Please add some more details about each of these choices, and link to authorities using them or defining them, if you can.